# Storing Data in Spark In Memory

Tags: apache-spark, in-memory

I have got a requirement of keeping the data in Spark's in memory in table format even when the `SparkContext` object dies, so that `Tableau` can access it.

I have used `registerTempTable` , but data gets removed once the `SparkContext` object dies. 
Is it possible to store data like this?If not what possible way I can look into to feed data to Tableau without reading it from HDFS location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do one of the below:

1. run your Spark application as a long running application. Spark streaming usually does that out of the box (when you do `StreamingContext.awaitTermination()`). I have never tried it myself but I think YARN and MESOS have support for **long running tasks**. As you mentioned whenever your `SparkContext` dies, all the data is lost (because all the information is stored in the context). I consider `spark-shell` a long running application, that's why most Tableau/Spark demos use it because the context never dies.
2. store it into a data store (HDFS, database, etc.)
3. Try to use some distributed in-memory framework/file system like Tachyon - not sure if it has Tableau connectors, though.

Comment: We are not looking to spark streaming as of now.. apart from that what you are saying is run the code from spark-shell.. so that the sparkcontext can be access any time.. this point can be considered for demo perspectives but not for practical implementation. Secondly I dont want to store the data in HDFS, I want to keep the data in memory in tabular format. I will look into Tachyon .

Comment: @AviraKumar spark streaming and spark shell were just examples, with mormal spark application you can make an infinite loop 'while(true){}' thanks to which your application wont die and will be a long running application. You need to figure a way to kill the application somehow then, though.

Comment: You can look at `ContextWaiter` class and `awaitTeination()` method in Spark github to see how they create lpng running applications. The idea is that your Spark application doesn't finish but live in the cluster.

Comment: okay cool will check Mateusz.. hows the option of saveAsTable?

Comment: @AviralKumar that option writes to a `HiveMetastore`, not something you want.

Answer (score 0):

Does Tableau read data from custom Spark Application?

I use PowerBi (instead Tableau) and it queries Spark through Thrift client, so each time it dies and restarts, I send him "cache table myTable" query through odbc/jdbc driver

Answer (score 0):

I came to know a very interesting answer to the question asked above.
TACHYON. 
http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/5/exercises/tachyon.html